# Accuracy for unfairness detection

Tags: bias, model-evaluation, accuracy, metric, algorithmic-fairness

I am dealing with unfairness and I am trying to find out some metrics to detect unfairness presence in my dataset. I am starting from the very bases: **accuracy**. My main question is **Do you think I can get any hint on unfairness (discrimination) with this metric?**

I made some computations and got these results for accuracy:

```
sex   old   full_data  unbiased  biased
0      0    0.9008     0.9256    0.9455
0      1    0.9028     0.9770    0.9273
1      0    0.9016     0.9239    0.9613
1      1    0.9145     0.9606    0.9048
```

where:

1. `sex` is 0 for women and 1 for men
2. `old` is 0 for not_old and 1 for old
3. `full_data` means the accuracy is calculated on the whole dataset (which contains both fair and unfair observations), considering only with those coupled values of sex and old
4. `unbiased` means the accuracy is calculated only on observations which are labelled as "unbiased", considering only with those coupled values of sex and old
5. `biased` means the accuracy is calculated only on observations which are labelled as "biased", considering only with those coupled values of sex and old

So, can accuracy give information on bias? Or can you suggest any other metric (or link) I should try?

Thanks you in advance

Comment: Could you explain what "unfairness" means here and how it is related to the statistical summaries you show?

Comment: Hi @whuber, thanks for asking. Suppose you have a dataset with some individuals: males and females, young and old. My question is: do you think the summaries I am showing can in some way say when there is unfairness (meaning, for example, I give a job to an old man instead of a young woman)?

Comment: It would help to have an explanation of how these statistics are related to awarding jobs.  Currently there's not enough context in this question to be able to interpret the numbers.

Comment: I created a model and then I applied it to my data. These numbers are the calculated metrics from the confront of predictions and ground truth. Example: when sex=0 and old=0, the accuracy of a dataset composed by only biased data is 0.9256

Comment: In this context, then, what does "fairness" mean?

Comment: For example, having men and women with similar rates